# Bastion host redirect url to other host in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache2

I have an application exist and running in the host1 aws machine with the url as http://abcabc.com and I have introduced a bastion host to reduce the server calls to my host1 aws machine.

bastion host has apche2 server, What configuration I have to make so that I can access http://abcabc.com url from bastion host from end user.

Comment: Please do not use other people's domain names as examples in your posts. Names like http://example.com and http://example.org have been set aside for exactly such purposes.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the Apache Reverse Proxy Server on your Bastion Host.

However, you will need to use a different URL to directly access the site via the reverse proxy (unless you intend to move the domain name to the reverse proxy). The URL http://abcabc.com points to host1 aws machine. You cannot use the same URL for two different systems independently. The same URL to different systems supports load balancing, failover, geolocation, etc.

**Apache Reverse Proxy:**

- Here is a [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-apache-as-a-reverse-proxy-with-mod_proxy-on-ubuntu-16-04) for Ubuntu and Apache.
- Here is a [link](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/reverse_proxy.html) for Apache Reverse Proxy Guide.

**Warning:**

Now that I have shown you how, rethink what you are doing. Bastion hosts are designed to provide protection for instances / services inside private subnets. You are adding services that weaken the Bastion host.

You are also adding another point of failure / monitoring / management headache. If either the webserver or the reverse proxy fails, your site is down.

> I have introduced a bastion host to reduce the server calls to my
>   host1 aws machine.

Are you misusing `Bastion Host` and instead mean Caching Frontend? In this case do not use a Reverse Proxy and instead setup [Google Cloud CDN](https://cloud.google.com/cdn/) in front of your website to cache its contents.